# Unable to run a selenium-junit project having maven in jmeter

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, jmeter

Hi i am trying to execute Jmeter Junit sampler having maven dependencies.

I have included all selenium jars into the lib folder along with the standalone server.
Also , my pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MySeleniumLoadTest</groupId>
<artifactId>MySeleniumLoadTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version> -->
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>    <!-- our scope is not test but compile -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
<groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
<artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
<executions>
    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
    <execution>
        <id>configuration</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>configure</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
    <execution>
        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>jmeter</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
    <execution>
        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>results</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

org.eclipse.m2e
                lifecycle-mapping
                1.0.0
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        com.lazerycode.jmeter
                                    
                                    
                                        jmeter-maven-plugin
                                    
                                    
                                        [3.1.1,)
                                    
                                    
                                        configure

Whenever i import the following jar file into the lib/junit folder, and execute the junit sampler, the code does not get executed on selecting Junit 4 and the class name. Also there is no error shown in view results tree. I am attaching my [jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Na9g6ZZaQ3EjjJZ3eJaiDY0EjyDLzWKo/view?usp=sharing) file. Could you please point out what mistake i am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see the error in the View Results Tree listener only if sampler can be executed, if it cannot be executed due to improper JMeter configuration - you should be looking for error messages in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Also the way you're adding dependencies is not suitable for JMeter Maven Plugin, it uses [Eclipse Aether](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.aether) which has different [dependencies resolution logic](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Resolving_Dependencies)

So you need to change your *pom.xml* file to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testPlanLibraries>
                        <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.testng:testng:6.4.13</artifact>
                        <artifact>io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:3.8.1</artifact>
                    </testPlanLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Once done you should put the .jar containing **only your test code** to the "lib/junit" folder of your JMeter installation

More information:

- [Adding Excluding libraries to from the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)
- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)